# Como adicionar uma biblioteca JQuery no Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, mask

Eu estava precisando adicionar uma biblioteca Jquery no magento 1.9, para usar em umas das minhas páginas phtml, para inserir máscaras nos meus campos, como cpf, cnpj e etc ...

Realizei diversas pesquisas e obserservei que o assunto é muito escasso, mas muito necessário, e quero compartilhar esse conhecimento com vocês. Existem vários detalhes para se atentar, mas com muita paciência dá certo, descobri o método correto e indicado para fazer essa operação, e também descobri o método rápido, caso o primeiro método não funcione.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom pesquisei bastante, e consegui duas soluções, a primeira é assim, você adiciona o arquivo Jquery.js que deseja no diretório **magento/js/jquery/nome-da-sua-lib.js**.

Feito isso, você vai procurar pelo arquivo page.xml, e adicionar um método addJs que aponta para o local onde você inseriu seu arquivojquery.js. (Função addJS, explicarei logo abaixo)

Ex de localização: `app/design/frontend/default/seutema/layout/page.xml`.

Certo, chegando no page.xml verás um method chamando **addJS** que basicamente é uma função nativa do magento que tem como objetivo buscar no diretório JS do magento, o arquivo que você deseja adicionar. Preste bastante atenção aqui, ele já está setado para procurar na pasta **JS** do magento, então basicamente, tu irá apenas digitar depois dessa pasta.

Então vamos por exemplo, adicionar uma biblioteca JQuery.js:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/nome-da-sua-lib-jquery.js</script></action>
```

Observe que eu não digitei **js/jquery/.....** eu apenas digitei **jquery/....** sendo assim seguindo o que eu falei mais acima, que o js já está setado e não precisa ser referenciado na sua informação sobre o diretório.

Seguindo esses passos você já terá no seu Magento a sua biblioteca Jquery, e depois é só usar para sua vontade. Para saber que está funcionando, recarregue o magento, ative o console do navegador e busque no html a tag head e veja as bibliotecas jquerys intanciadas lá, se estiver aparecendo lá, está ok.

SE VOCÊ NÃO CONSEGUIU USANDO O PRIMEIRO MÉTODO(MAIS INDICADO) ... Lembre-se pode ser mais fácil, porém aconselho a utilizar a primeira maneira...

***SEGUNDA FORMA***

É basicamente a primeira coisa que se pensa na hora de fazer algo do tipo.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('jquery/nome-da-sua-lib-jquery.js')?>"></script>
```

**Observações finais: Sintaxe Jquery Magento 1.9**

No seu arquivo.phtml, quando você tentar usar uma função no seu Jquery, utilizando sua biblioteca que acabou de adicionar, e receber algum erro. Tente utilizar esse estilo de sintaxe:

```
jQuery('input[id="billing:exemplo"]').mask("(00)00000-0000");
```